# Redirect to WWW except for Wildcard DNS

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, dns, wildcard

So I'm working on a web application much similar to Guild Hosting & Clan Hosting sites. But I'm having a problem with the HTACCESS and PHP.

Here is my **.HTACCESS** file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+?)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule .* /index.php?site=%1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/?site=$1 [L,R=301]
```

Here is my **INDEX.PHP** file:

```
<?php
$site = explode(".", $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]);

if(sizeof($site === 3) && $site[0] == "www") {
    echo "Welcome to MySite!";
} else {
    if(isset($_GET["site"])) {
        echo "Welcome to " . $_GET["site"] . "!";
    } else {
        header("Location: http://www.example.com/");
    }
}
?>
```

What I want the code to do is if they go to the main site it just echos that basic message but I keep getting

```
http://www.example.com/?site=
```

at the end of my domain when I don't want anything there, I also want to be able to make it so the site redirects to a subdomain of the specified site e.g.

```
http://www.example.com/?site=test => http://test.example.com or http://www.test.example.com
```

I then want the htaccess file to get the information from

```
http://www.example.com/?site=test/
```

like the htaccess currently does, anyone know how I could achieve all of this in HTACESS and PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was bored of waiting for an answer and so I messed around with my .HTACESS file and it works!
Here is my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+?)\.example.com$
RewriteRule .* /index.php?site=%1 [L]
```

and the `index.php` file manages redirecting to the WWW site:

```
<?php
$site = explode(".", $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]);

if(sizeof($site === 3) && $site[0] == "www") {
    echo "Welcome to Main Site!";
} else {
    if(isset($_GET["site"])) {
        echo "Welcome to " . $_GET["site"] . "!";
    } else {
        header("Location: http://www.example.com/");
    }
}
?>
```